# How to get a value of jquery variable

Tags: jquery

Jquery Code:

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
        var ma = $("#qty").val();
        var str = $("#reqid").val();
        $("#myform").validate({
            rules: {
                issue_quant_str: {
                    max: ma
                }
            }
        });
    });​
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr><td><?php echo $array['item_name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $array['quantity']; ?></td>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $array['requisition_id']; ?>" id="reqid" /> 
    <td>
        <div id="maxdiv">
            <input type="text" name="issue_quant_<?php echo $array ['requisition_id'];?>" value="<?php echo $array['quantity']; ?>" />
        </div>
    </td>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $stock_qty; ?>" id="qty" /> 
    <td><?php echo $stock_qty;?></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="rem_<?php echo $array['requisition_id'];?>" required/></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here I want var str value to be concatenated with issue_quant.I am not getting str value.Can anyone help me out..

Comment: show your code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Can you post your `html` code?

Comment: does element with id "reqid" exists in HTML document? can u see that element using firebug?

Answer (score 1):

```
var rules = {};
rules['issue_quant_' + str] = {max:ma};
$("#myform").validate({
    rules: rules
});
```

Comment: can u please help me out with this

Answer (score 0):

try `var str=$("#reqid").text();`

provided that your `reqid` lives in your html code and has some value inside