# Jquery getting variable value

Tags: php, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get a value of jquery variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052379/how-to-get-a-value-of-jquery-variable)

JS:

```
<script>   
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var ma = $("#qty").val();
        var str = $("#reqid").val();
        var iss = 'issue_quant_' + str;
        $("#myform").validate({
            rules: {
                iss: {
                    max: ma
                }
            }
        });

    }); 
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<td> 
    <input type="text" name="issue_quant_<?php echo $array['requisition_id'];?>" />
</td>
```

The script is not taking the `str` value. If I get my texbox named as `iss` it works, but it doesn't work like this.

Comment: what are you trying to do? and what do you mean by this?

Comment: This is because you don't have any value in the input field.

Comment: No it doesnt work with value as well

Comment: I am trying to limit the input feild to certain value

Comment: Also the input should have the id "reqid"

Comment: you dont have that id in your html, so where should js take that value,

Comment: Everything else is correct..I just want to know how can i get actual value of var iss in validate function

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you are passing an object with key `iss` for the `rules` property. What you need to do is pass an object with key `issue_quant_<?php echo $array['requisition_id'];?>`.

In your previous question, which is very similar to this one, I have already shown you how you can create an object with a variable key:

```
var iss = 'issue_quant_' + str;
var rules = {};
rules[iss] = {max: ma};
$("#myform").validate({
    rules: rules
});
```

Assuming that `'issue_quant_' + str` evaluates to the value of `issue_quant_<?php echo $array['requisition_id'];?>`, the validation rule will be applied to the input.

Comment: @Sharvari I have already shown you how to do this in your previous question, which is almost identical.

Comment: but this is giving me error

Comment: @Sharvari There are a billion reasons you could be getting an error. Unless you tell me what the error is, I cannot help you.

Comment: This isnt working for me...

Comment: @Sharvari I accidentally put a semicolon in the object literal. Try it now.

Comment: no it was not helpful...nyways thanks for giving your time